# C++ Windows Error loading shared libraries

Tags: c++, windows, protocol-buffers, bazel

I am getting the following error. I am on Windows 10 using bazel 4.0 and msys2.

```
C:/Users/katso/Documents/Github/KeirosPublic/bazel-out/x64_windows-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/protoc.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

when I run this command

```
bazel-out/x64_windows-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/protoc.exe --proto_path=bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/_virtual_imports/timestamp_proto --java_out=bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/Security/Proto/validity_period_proto-speed-src.jar -ISecurity/Proto/validity_period.proto=Security/Proto/validity_period.proto -Igoogle/protobuf/timestamp.proto=bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/_virtual_imports/timestamp_proto/google/protobuf/timestamp.proto --direct_dependencies google/protobuf/timestamp.proto:Security/Proto/validity_period.proto
```

An easy way to recreate this is as follows

`WORKSPACE`

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

# rules_cc defines rules for generating C++ code from Protocol Buffers.
http_archive(
    name = "rules_cc",
    sha256 = "35f2fb4ea0b3e61ad64a369de284e4fbbdcdba71836a5555abb5e194cf119509",
    strip_prefix = "rules_cc-624b5d59dfb45672d4239422fa1e3de1822ee110",
    urls = [
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/archive/624b5d59dfb45672d4239422fa1e3de1822ee110.tar.gz",
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/archive/624b5d59dfb45672d4239422fa1e3de1822ee110.tar.gz",
    ],
)

# rules_java defines rules for generating Java code from Protocol Buffers.
http_archive(
    name = "rules_java",
    sha256 = "ccf00372878d141f7d5568cedc4c42ad4811ba367ea3e26bc7c43445bbc52895",
    strip_prefix = "rules_java-d7bf804c8731edd232cb061cb2a9fe003a85d8ee",
    urls = [
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_java/archive/d7bf804c8731edd232cb061cb2a9fe003a85d8ee.tar.gz",
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_java/archive/d7bf804c8731edd232cb061cb2a9fe003a85d8ee.tar.gz",
    ],
)

# rules_proto defines abstract rules for building Protocol Buffers.
http_archive(
    name = "rules_proto",
    sha256 = "2490dca4f249b8a9a3ab07bd1ba6eca085aaf8e45a734af92aad0c42d9dc7aaf",
    strip_prefix = "rules_proto-218ffa7dfa5408492dc86c01ee637614f8695c45",
    urls = [
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_proto/archive/218ffa7dfa5408492dc86c01ee637614f8695c45.tar.gz",
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_proto/archive/218ffa7dfa5408492dc86c01ee637614f8695c45.tar.gz",
    ],
)

load("@rules_cc//cc:repositories.bzl", "rules_cc_dependencies")
rules_cc_dependencies()

load("@rules_java//java:repositories.bzl", "rules_java_dependencies", "rules_java_toolchains")
rules_java_dependencies()
rules_java_toolchains()

load("@rules_proto//proto:repositories.bzl", "rules_proto_dependencies", "rules_proto_toolchains")
rules_proto_dependencies()
rules_proto_toolchains()
```

`BUILD`

```
proto_library(
  name = "my_proto",
  srcs = ["my.proto"]
)

cc_proto_library(
  name = "my_cc_proto",
  deps = [":my_proto"]
)
```

`my.proto`

```
message MyProto {
  int64 value = 1;
}
```

If you run some version of this command you will get the command you can then run to reproduce this.

`bazel build :all --compiler=mingw-gcc --verbose_failures`

Let me know if you are missing anything else that might be helpful. This basically breaks the mingw compiler for bazel. I cannot use the normal MSVC one because I have dependencies that are only buildable in mingw.

I ran `ldd protoc.exe` and got

```
        ntdll.dll => /c/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7ffcfa410000)
        KERNEL32.DLL => /c/Windows/System32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x7ffcf89f0000)
        KERNELBASE.dll => /c/Windows/System32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7ffcf7f70000)
        msvcrt.dll => /c/Windows/System32/msvcrt.dll (0x7ffcf86e0000)
```

which makes no sense because my `PATH` is `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:C:/Users/katso/Documents/Github/KeirosPublic/bazel-out/x64_windows-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/:/c/Users/katso/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Users/katso/Documents/Github/KeirosPublic/bazel-out/x64_windows-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/:/c/Windows/SYSTEM32`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by passing the following flags to the compiler

`--copt="-static-libgcc"` and  `--copt="-static-libstdc++"` and `--copt="-static"`